# Why can't I run this C program?

Tags: c, compiler

I'm trying to run my first "process" program, but I get the following error :

```
./fork.c: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./fork.c: line 4: `int main()'
```

I'm pretty sure that the code is correct:

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main() {
     pid_t pid;
     printf("Hello fork()\n");
     switch(pid=fork())  {
         case -1: printf("Error by fork().....\n"); exit(0);
         case 0: printf("I'm the child process \n"); break;
         default: printf("I'm the dad \n"); break;
     }
  exit(0);
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Just for the sake of your own sanity later, put a "break;" on the "case -1:" line.  You'll thank yourself for it later.  Also, have the child process call  _exit(0), and the parent call exit(0).

Comment: @BruceEdiger Why the need for `_exit`? What's wrong with doing any cleanup that's been registered?

Comment: exit(0) will flush stdout and stderr. _exit(0) will not. You can end up with double outputs if there's some bytes on stdout when your program does the fork(), and the child calls exit(0). Because you're learning how fork() works why confuse yourself?

Comment: @BruceEdiger learning how `fork()` works includes learning that it can copy buffered output. Being a reasonably complicated system call, some confusion is probably necessary in the learning process.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can't just run `./fork.c`. It's not a program; it's the **source** for a program. Using `./` assumes that the file is a script (which it isn't) and treats it accordingly.

However, as noted in another answer, there are compilers (like [Tiny C Compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/)) that can execute C code without explicitly compiling it.

Since it's a C program, you have to compile the program. Try `cc -o fork fork.c` then `./fork`; it worked here.

Comment: And if your on Linux, it's probably GCC, not CC.

Comment: @Linuxios in most Linux systems, `cc` is a symbolic link to `gcc`.

Comment: Good to know. Although it points to something else on systems like Slaris, right?

Comment: Probably; I don't have access to a Solaris system here.

Comment: Neither do I, ,that's just what I've seen.

Comment: Just checked a couple of Solaris boxes, and `/usr/bin/cc` links to `/opt/SUNWspro/bin/cc` on one and `/opt/sunstudio12.1/bin/cc` on the other. Regardless, it's still a C compiler.

Comment: And on an HPUX box it's `/opt/ansic/bin/cc`.

Comment: be sure you changed your arch, you run amd64 under 32.ok?

Comment: @OrangeDog On Solaris, Sun studio needs to be installed for cc to work... On Solaris 10, `gcc` is installed in `/usr/sfw/bin` in a default full install, which is useful if you do not have a Sun studio / Oracle Solaris Studio image nearby...

Answer (score 23):

That's not a program, that's the source code for a program.

C is a *compiled* language, meaning it must be "compiled" into machine-readable instructions before you can run it. As you are using C, the "C Compiler" (`cc`) can do this.

```
cc -o fork for.c   # compile the code
chmod +x fork      # ensure it it executable
./fork             # run the compiled program
```

As you move on to more complicated programs, using multiple source files and external libraries, you'll likely move on to using the "GNU Compiler Collection" (`gcc`) and `make` to describe how to turn the source code into a working executable.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286552/difference-between-script-and-program) has various information on the difference between scripts (as you are attempting to treat your source code) and compiled programs.

Comment: If "compiler" is part of the name of the tool, I would call that reasonably explicit.

Comment: Just a note that the tools I named are not the only ones available, but are likely to be available by default on a GNU/Linux system and are widely used.

Comment: Regarding that "must" word, `tcc` ([Tiny C Compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/)) can execute C code without explicitly compiling it. http://pastebin.com/5FZiMpEn (Edited comment by re-adding it. Sorry for messing the order.)